# Razor Engine Issue in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I declare a text box in view page the below error will appear

```
 The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>)'
 cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
 explicitly
```

even I included

```xml
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <!-- ... -->
</compilation>
```

this in `webconfig` file 
but the same error shows .
............
my code

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Entity, new { @id = "Entityname" })
```

//..........
**model**

```
public string Entity { set; get; }
```

//.........
//..............
**.cshtml page**

```
  @model BOSSNew.Models.NewQuantifierM
    @{Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
    <div class="breadCrumbHolder">
        @{Html.RenderAction("BreadCrumb", "Base", new { menulist = new string[] { "Quantifier", "New Quantifier" }, CurrentURL = new string[] { "#", "#" } });}
    </div>
    <div class="divContentPane">
        <div class="contentPaneHead">
            <span class="contentPaneTitle">Users Details </span>
        </div>
        <table class="ClsTable ClsPad0">
            <tr class="even">
                <th>@LabelHelper.GetLabel("THLentity", 3)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Entity, new { @id = "Entityname" })
                    <img title="" id="selectentit" style="margin: 5px" onclick="getentity('txtentity','optentity')"
                        alt="" src="../../../Name.Controls/Themes/Name-Theme/images/entity.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

//.............

Any idea ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can we see the textbox line that make that error?

Comment: @clement sorry now you can check

Comment: and what about the model that is passed into the view? did you include once? can we see it?

Comment: I don`t think that you can use TextBoxFor for a whole Entity. Try EditorFor, or use TextBoxFor for a property in your Entity.

Comment: What is property `Entity`? If its not a complex object, then it wont work.

Comment: @clement please check i have included that too

Comment: strange.. did you try to rename the Entity to lorem or something else?

Comment: How are you setting the value of `Entity` in the GET method - it could possibly be an issue with a database query?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined model for a view, so you can't use

> x => x.Field

expression.

It should look more or less like that:

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@model SomeModel
@{Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
    <div class="breadCrumbHolder">
        @{Html.RenderAction("BreadCrumb", "Base", new { menulist = new string[] { "Quantifier", "New Quantifier" }, CurrentURL = new string[] { "#", "#" } });}
    </div>
    <div class="divContentPane">
        <div class="contentPaneHead">
            <span class="contentPaneTitle">Users Details </span>
        </div>
        <table class="ClsTable ClsPad0">
            <tr class="even">
                <th>@LabelHelper.GetLabel("THLentity", 3)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Entity, new { @id = "Entityname" })
                    <img title="" id="selectentit" style="margin: 5px" onclick="getentity('txtentity','optentity')"
                        alt="" src="../../../Name.Controls/Themes/Name-Theme/images/entity.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

**SomeModel.cs**

```
public class SomeModel
{
   public string Entity { set; get; }
}
```

And finally in your action method...

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
   var model = new SomeModel();
   //here fill the entity field
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: yes i have defined model please check. i have removed it from here because it contains some sensitive infromation about our project . anyway check question now

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe a silly question - is your model class public?